# After Exporting Database should be empty

Tags: mysql, delete

I am exporting data from database for that I have written following query:

```
SELECT ParameterID, Name,Type,Datatype,LogDate
FROM Param_Ems
WHERE DataType = 10
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/ParamData.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Is there any way to export and delete these records within the same query?

Comment: There is no standard SQL (as far as I know ) to achieve this. Are you trying to achieve a better performance or you can't run two queries? Your objective is not clear to me.

Comment: I want to clear exported data from database after exporting

Comment: Yeah... I understood your question but don't know why are you trying to do this?! because alternatives are not any faster than running the query twice.

Comment: Because same data will be log into database again.

Comment: I just find the solution in one query if not then i have to make two queries

Comment: There is no single query that can export and delete the rows in MySQL.

Comment: Just stay logged in !

Answer (score 0):

Use pt-archiver tool. It can delete data that it moves. Alternatively use drop & create after the select into outfile.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` and `TRUNCATE (or DROP) TABLE` in a stored procedure; then `CALL` the SP.

(Caveat:  I am not sure if those two statements can be performed in a SP.)

Comment: And `TRUNCATE` does an auto-commit, if I remember right.

Comment: The commit would probably be OK.  If not, the change to a `DELETE`, which would be slower.